How do we get rid of $p(x|\theta)$ in MLE
Simple question... usually the intro to ML tells you the following:

you want to maximize $p(\theta|D)$, thus the optimization is $\theta = \arg\max_\theta p(\theta|D)$
bayes theorem tells us that $p(\theta|D) \propto p(D|\theta)p(\theta)$, thus $\theta = \arg\max_\theta p(D|\theta)p(\theta)$
if you consider $p(\theta)$ constant, you get MLE, if you consider it Gaussian you get L2 regularization and so on

However, I was going a bit more in details, and here's my question:
$$
p(\theta|D) \propto p(D|\theta)p(\theta) = p(x,y|\theta)p(\theta) = p(y|x, \theta)p(x|\theta)p(\theta)
$$
Now, usually what we optimize is actually $p(y|x,\theta)p(\theta)$, so my question is... under which assumption do we remove $p(x|\theta)$?
Do we consider $x$ being indipendent to $\theta$ and being constant?...

I do not understand your question, nor the distinction between $D$ and $x$ which both look as if you are using them to represent the observed data.  Maximum likelihood estimation is not a Bayesian method so does not involve prior and posterior distributions.  Aiming for the MLE simply involves finding the $\theta$ which maximises $p(x \mid \theta)$ since the likelihood is proportional to that.

@Henry $D$ is the dataset, which is a joint distribution of $x$ and $y$ (yes you can consider them together under the same name, but ultimately you have some covariates and some response variables, thus the 2 distinct names), and with discriminative tasks you aim at maximizing $p_\theta(y|x)$, not all $p_\theta(x)$

@Henry and yes, I get that MLE is not bayesian, never said that, I'm fine with a point estimate, but still you have to handle that $p(x|\theta)$, thus p(covariates|parameters) in some way

Well, actually, you did say that, with the three statements "you want to maximize $p(\theta|D)$, "you apply Bayes' theorem" and "if you consider $p(\theta)$ constant, you get MLE."  No, you get a posterior distribution which, if you calculate the Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) estimate, will provide the same numerical value as if you had found the MLE.   As @Henry has observed, to find the MLE you don't do any of that; you simply find the $\theta$ which maximizes $p(x|\theta)$, which does not assume there exists a $p(\theta|D)$, a $p(\theta)$, etc.

Some frequentists would not only object to notations like $p(\theta)$ and $p(\theta|D)$ unless we're in a Bayesian setup in which the $\theta$ is treated as random, they would also object against writing $p(x|\theta)$ because $\theta$ is not random and therefore this is not a conditional probability as the notation suggests. Instead they would write $p_\theta(x)$ to clearly show that $x$ is random but $\theta$ is not.

Furthermore, regression is often analysed assuming also the $x$ to be fixed and only the $y$ to be random, in which case not even $p_\theta(x)$ is valid, rather only $p_{\theta,x}(y)$ or (more familiar) something like $p_\theta(e)$ with $e=y-f_\theta(x)$, allowing $\theta$ to comprise both regression and error variance parameters.

@jbowman I've edited the question and specified that I'm interested in a point estimate, and that I'm using bayes theorem only to refactor the objective

@ChristianHennig thanks, I see how notation might play an important role, however my question wants merely to address how do you get MLE via this derivation, which is used many times skipping the details (and thus not explainin why $p(x|\theta)$ can be removed)

You are asking one question in the post and another in the comments.  Again, you don't get the MLE with this derivation; the MLE doesn't use a prior distribution, and $p(\theta|D)$ is not a part of the MLE calculations.  Your posted question is different, though.

I might be misreading the title, but how would it make sense to to get rid of the likelihood ($p(x|\theta)$) in maximum-likelihood estimation?

@Firebug usually by considering them a constant, that you can remove as it does not contribute to the maximization for example if x is independent from $\theta$, than you can remove it, i suppose

Once again, the likelihood is what's maximized in maximum likelihood estimation.  As @Firebug observes, more politely than me, it makes no sense to get rid of the likelihood when it's what you maximize in maximum likelihood estimation.  It doesn't "contribute" to the maximization, it is what's maximized.

@jbowman the MLE that I ultimately ideally want to optimize in a regression problem is $p(y|x,\theta)$, not the likelihood $p(x|\theta)$

$p(y|x,\theta)$ is a likelihood, just one that's conditional on $x$.  But... likelihood functions are conditional upon the data.  We could just as well write it as $L(\theta|y,x)$ and maximize that with respect to $\theta$. There's no need for $p(\theta)$ or forming $p(\theta|D)$ at all.  Where did you get the (erroneous) idea that you need to construct a prior $p(\theta)$ and a posterior $p(\theta|D)$ to do maximum likelihood estimation?

"usually by considering them a constant, that you can remove as it does not contribute to the maximization" your are answering 'how' you'd operationalize it, I'm asking 'why' do you want to get rid of the likelihood in likelihood maximization

@Firebug ideally i wanted to show that $max p(\theta|D) \propto max p(y|x,\theta)$ for discriminative tasks

The model you're describing, $p(y|x,\theta)p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$, is a stochastic regressor model.
You can get away with ignoring $p(x|\theta)$ when $\theta$ partitions into $(\theta_y, \theta_x)$ with both components being disjoint. For instance, if $p(y|x,\theta_y)$ is a linear regression, then the distribution of $x$ needs to be independent of $\theta_y = (\beta, \sigma^2)$, the parameters of $y$'s distribution.
$$
p (x|\theta) = p(x|\theta_{x}) \quad \text{where } \theta_y \cap \theta_x = \emptyset
$$
A special case of this would be regressors that don't have a probability distribution $p(x|\theta_x)$ at all because they are fixed in repeated samples.

So we can say that usually we get away removing it because we assume $\theta$ (being the parameters of the predictive model) are indipendent from $x$?

I guess you can think about it that way, but more precisely you're assuming that $p(x|\cdot)$ and $p(y|x,\cdot)$ don't share parameters.

We typically assume either that $x$ is fixed or that $x$ depends on different parameters from $y|x$ and it can be conditioned on.
That is, if $y=x\beta+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, it's quite plausible that the distribution of $x$ would not involve $\beta$ or $\sigma^2$, but would depend on other paramters.  In that sort of setting $p(y,x|\theta)$ could be written as
$p(y,x|\theta,eta)$ and factor as $p(y|x,\theta)p(x|\eta$.
There are situations where this sort of simplification doesn't hold. One is case-control sampling. If you fit a logistic regression model under case-control sampling, both the distribution of $x$ and the distribution of $y|x$ depend on the odds ratios $\beta$, and that fact that you can just ignore this and model $p(y|x,\beta)$ directly is a deep result.  For maximum likelihood esitmation of models other than logistic regression under case-control sampling you do need to model $(y,x)$ jointly, given all the parameters.


under which assumption do we remove $p(x|\theta)$?

If $x$ is independent from $\theta$ then $p(x|\theta) = p(x)$ and can be absorbed in the constant of proportionality.
$$p(\theta|x,y) \propto  p(y|x, \theta)p(x)p(\theta)$$
implies
$$p(\theta|x,y) \propto  p(y|x, \theta)p(\theta)$$
